# Microsoft Graph returns 401 even if I have a valid access token

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Currently I am trying to get all outlook user calendar events. I have followed all the instructions to set up Azure Active Directory V 2.0 and I am getting the access token doing:

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(
    {
      allowConsentPrompt: true,
      allowSignInPrompt: true,
    },
   (result) => {
      if (result.status === 'succeeded') {
        return result.value
      }

      return result.error
    },
  )
```

After this, I am trying to get user calendar events by doing:

```
fetch(
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`,
{
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'access-control-allow-origin': 'my.domain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    Prefer: 'outlook.timezone',
  }
}
```

)

In the end, I get a response 401 with the body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1fba5937-3106-460c-98a6-a1e7858b8116",
      "date": "2020-02-12T13:59:21"
    }
  }
}
```

I am currently stucked, I also tried to use instead of graph.microsoft.com to use the Office.context.mailbox.restUrl but that one does not accept the access token I have. Do I maybe skip something obvious?

PS: I forgot to mention that the scope permissions I gave to my add-in:

```
<Scopes>
      <Scope>user.read</Scope>
      <Scope>profile</Scope>
      <Scope>openid</Scope>
      <Scope>email</Scope>
      <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
      <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
      <Scope>calendars.read</Scope>
    </Scopes>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invalid audience` means that the token you have was issued for an API other than the one you are calling. If you copy the token and head over to https://jwt.ms, you can parse it and examine the `aud` claim. If it is not `https://graph.microsoft.com`, you can't use it to call Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jason, I have checked and the aud is the application id from Azure Portal of my app, was it supposed to be an url?

Comment: It can be, but if it's your app ID that just means it's a token granting permission to call your back-end web API. It's been a few years since I did anything with the Outlook add-in auth stuff, but I think they require that you do an on-behalf-of flow to exchange that token for a Graph token. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=outlook-js-1.8#getaccesstokenasync-options--callback-)

Comment: Jason is correct. Please see here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph

Comment: I completely misunderstood that step, thank you for the help guys!